# How to color numbers in a txt?

Tags: colors

I have 10.000 numbers in a txt file,from 0 to 36 and want to color them like they are on a roulette table.Can you give me hints what is the easiest way to do this?ANY method will do it.

Comment: I'm not really skilled in programming,only know the basics of c.

Comment: What does it mean "to color them". Do you want to print them colored on the terminal? Do you want to create pdf file with colored fonts?